# Getting data from a service always return the same value (not the updated) on AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

i'm doing a crud like a phone list,
in a view i want to add persons to my list, and in another view i want to show that peoples,
for do that, i'm using two controllers, and a service to store my array with the persons.
to add peoples i'm using set way to pushing it to array when i click on a button and thats works fine(possible to see with console.log at salvar function in service).
My problem is, when i go to show the list with the get method after added some persons with set, the get method still returning my list like she starts (empty). how i can fix this?

```
angular
    .module('moduloLista')
    .factory('addMostrarService', addMostrarService);

function addMostrarService() {

    var listacontatos =  [
       ];
    var salvar = function(obj){
        listacontatos.push(obj);
    };


    var getLista = function(){
        return listacontatos;




    };
   return{
       salvar: function(obj){
           salvar(obj);
       },
       getLista: function(){
           return getLista(); 
     }
   }   
}
```

^ Service Code

```
angular
    .module('moduloLista')
    .controller('testeController',testeController);

    testeController.$inject = ['addMostrarService'];

    function testeController(addMostrarService) {
           var vm = this;
           vm.dadoslista = addMostrarService.getLista();
           console.log('vm.dadoslista');


    }
```

^ controller to get the list from service.

Comment: In your `getLista` method you are returning `lista.contatos` when it looks like you should be returning `listacontatos`.

Comment: Thx bro but this inst the problem, that "." its just a mistake made when i've made the question

Comment: Your code is working fine, see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/45Lkq3yt/)

Comment: Yeah but, with one controller thats ok, but when u call get method from other controller in another view, the list come empty, do you know?

Comment: I have tested the same in my project( internal ) and it is working fine as you are expecting. Seems you are resetting the factory somewhere while routing. Please check